# How to dynamically filter a view by ModelChoiceField selection

Tags: django, filter, modelchoicefield

I have created a template that renders a dropdown list of students.

I want to filter a query set on another view to show schedule info for just the student that was selected.

perm_id in student_list is primary key and perm in StudentSchedule is foreign key.

Here are snippets of my models.py, forms.py and views.py

models.py

```
class StudentList(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    perm_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class StudentSchedule(models.Model):
    perm = models.ForeignKey(StudentList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    begin_period = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    section_id = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class StudentForm(forms.Form):
    Student = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StudentList.objects.all()
                                .order_by('student_name'))
```

views.py

```
class ScheduleView(View):
   form_class = ScheduleForm
   template_name = 'learning_logs/student_schedule.html'

   def get(self, request):
       form = self.form_class(initial={})
       data = StudentSchedule.objects.filter()
       return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'data': 
data})
```

I can do the following and get student with id # 123456

```
data = StudentSchedule.objects.filter(perm=123456)
```

But, I want Django to use the perm_id from the student selected from StudentList

My urls are as follows:

```
# Page for selecting a student from drop down list
path('select_student/', views.StudentView.as_view(), name='select_student'),

# Page for displaying student schedule
path('student_schedule/<int:pk>/$', views.ScheduleView.as_view(), 
name='student_schedule'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your path is like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('students/<int:pk>/$', views.ScheduleView.as_view(), name='student-detail'),
    ...
]
```

Then you will get a additional  argument in your get method and you can access that as

```
class ScheduleView(View):
   form_class = ScheduleForm
   template_name = 'learning_logs/student_schedule.html'

   def get(self, request, pk):
       form = self.form_class(initial={})
       data = StudentSchedule.objects.filter(perm=pk)
       return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'data': 
data})
```

#### Edit

And also in your `student_schedule.html` you need to perm.id to access this url as

```
{% url ...  perm.id%}
```

Comment: Did as you suggested and received the following error:

Comment: Reverse for 'student_schedule' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['student_schedule/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\$$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for 'student_schedule' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['student_schedule/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\$$']

Comment: @ScottNorman you need to add prem.id in your accessing url. I have updated my response.